# What keyboards have the most programmable keys?

Tags: keyboards

Aside from the genovation/x-keys specialist keyboards, I am looking for a qwerty keyboard that I can program to shortcuts for software like Photoshop, Sound Forge, Vegas etc.

I'd need the keyboard

- to be back lit
- to have key caps that can be taken off the board (I'd like to sand off the face and apply a transparent print to it)
- to have software that comes with it (don't have time to use ahk and all that)
- [edit] be used as a second keyboard without it interfering with my laptop keyboard

Would like it (not necessary)

- to be Compact (my laptop is 480mm wide) - something about the same width would be perfect
- silent keys
- carry case

I know of the Razer deathstalker, but it doesn't seem I can remove the caps.

[edit] My budget is upto £100.

Comment: Would you be open to simpler "key automation"/shortcut software?

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: key automation"/shortcut software, is ok as long as it requires no coding and long winded set up. HID macros, lua macros ahk is all out of the question.

Comment: ahk = AHK = [AutoHotkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) (Windows only)

Answer (score 2):

The [Logitech G910 Orion Spark](https://www.newegg.com/global/uk/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16823126397) seems to fit your criteria. I am not a fan of the switches, but you might like them considering you want silent keys.

On Newegg, it is about £10 more than your budget.

It is definitely backlit, has removable keys, and has software to customize the lighting.

There are 9 programmable keys, which can be used for basically anything.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is not what you really wants, but the [palette gear solution](https://monogramcc.com/how-it-works) looks very good in terms of customizability and compatibility with Adobe products.

With such a device you can:

- Keep your keyboard / mouse for the normal use
- have sliders, potentiometers or buttons in the order you want
- configure each controls to your needs and per software

I did not try it myself but a French magazine tried and they had a good feedback about it (and this is my feeling as well).

Comment: this looks great, but unfortunately its very pricey and there wouldn't be enough buttons.

Comment: Yes this is as well the reason I did not try it. Additionally it is not very portable (compared to another keyboard) if you need to use it while traveling

Comment: Note however you can add as much controls as you want, but the budget will just get bigger and bigger.